# find the supremum and infimum of $B=\left\{\frac{m n}{3 m^{2}+n}: m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to find the supremum and infimum of the following set $B$ just by definition of sup and inf (not limits or derivative, etc.)
$$B=\left \{\frac{m n}{3 m^{2}+n}: m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

What I was trying to do is $$0\leq(m-n)^2=m^2-2mn+n^2 $$
$$ \frac{2mn}{m^2 +n^2}\leq 1$$ which is not helping me so much.
I would like to ask for any advice/guidline how to approach this problem.

Comment: You can just multiply m with 3 and then you will get expression smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @beingmathematician it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is not bounded. To prove this, take $n=3m^2.$ Then
$$\frac{mn}{3m^2+n}=\frac{m}{2}$$
Since $m\in \mathbb{Z},$ there is no supremum neither infimum.